# Spring Data JPA: Filter by one Field, sort by another field and get first

Tags: spring-data-jpa, query-builder, spring-repositories

Let's say have a table with the following columns:
STATUS - SUBMITTED - USER_ID

I would like query the repository interface in order to get the row that was SUBMITTED last by a certain USER_ID.

I know there is `findByUserId(long userId)` and `findFirstByOrderBySubmittedDesc()`, but I have no clue how to combine them.

How do I combine these two methods?

Answer (score 4):

Okay I figured it out by trial and error:

```
findFirstByUserIdOrderBySubmittedDesc(long userId)
```

Maybe this is helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

In your repo define a method:

```
Page<YourEntity> findByUserId(Long userId, Pageable page)
```

Call it like this. Create a `Pageable`:

```
Pageable firstBySubmittedDescending = 
  PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by("submitted").descending());
```

Pass it to your method.

Remember you get a `Page` not one entity. You need to call `getContent()` on the page to get it.